# $n$-vertex $3$-edge-colored graphs with exactly $6$ automorphisms which preserve edge color classes, but permute the edge colors distinctly?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

In each of these $3$-edge-colored graphs, there are exactly $6$ automorphisms which preserve the set of edge color classes:

[image: examples for 4,5,6 vertices]

(These automorphisms don't necessarily map e.g. green edges to green edges, but if one green edge is mapped to e.g. a blue edge, then every green edge is mapped to some blue edge.)

Moreover, in each example, each of these $6$ automorphisms permutes the colors differently.

**Question**: For all $n \geq 3$, does there exist an $n$-vertex graph such that (a) we have exactly $6$ automorphisms which preserve the set of edge color classes, and (b) each of these $6$ automorphisms gives rise to a different permutation of the edge colors?

---

These come from partial Latin rectangles with a certain symmetry.  E.g. the one on the right comes from
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
2 & 3 & \cdot \\
3 & \cdot & \cdot \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
by making the entries the vertex set and adding a green edge when two entries share a row, an orange edge when they share a column, and a blue edge when they share a symbol.  This partial Latin rectangle has a trivial autotopism group and an automorphism group isomorphic to $S_3$ (which gives rise to the symmetry property of the graph).

It's possible that I might be able to reverse this construction, and construct interesting partial Latin rectangles this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proffering the following construction even though it feels "too simple".

Assume first that $n\equiv1\pmod3$. Consider a star shaped graph with one central vertex, and three "monocolor rays" of $(n-1)/3$ vertices emanating from it. Any graph automorphism must map the central vertex to itself, because it is the only vertex of degree three. It easily follows that a graph automorphism must permute the three rays. By construction all those 6 permutations preserve the edge-color classes.

Adding one isolated vertex covers the case $n\equiv2\pmod3$.

If $3\mid n$ replace the central vertex with a cycle of three so that one ray begins from each of the three vertices of the cycle. If $P_1,P_2,P_3$ are the three vertices of that cycle, connect $P_1$ and $P_2$ with an edge sharing the color of the ray starting from $P_3$, and permute that cyclically.

Comment: It might be more interesting if you add more requirements. I don't know what would be useful for the purposes of your goal of applying this to Latin rectangles.

Comment: Indeed it does seem to work (except we can't add two isolated vertices, as then we have both the trivial automorphism and the automorphism which swaps those two vertices both preserving edge colors).  It's possible I just asked a simple question because I was thinking about it the wrong way.

Comment: You're right. Sorry.

Comment: @Rebecca: I think I thought of a fix for the case $3\mid n$.

Comment: You get a lot more graphs with the following recipe: Triangulate the plane with equilateral triangles. Color the edges parallel to $x$-axis green, the rising edges orange and the descending edges blue. Pick a subset stable under the action of the symmetries of the triangle. The sets will have varying sizes depending on whether the origin is at a vertex or at a centroid of one of the triangles.